# How many 3-digit positive integers can be formed using the digit 0,1,2,3,4 and 5?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

1. No repetition of digits?
2. With repetition?
3. If the integer must be greater than 400? (no repetition)
4. If the integer must be even?
5. If the integer must be odd?
6. If the integer must be divisible by 5? (no repetition)
7. If the integer must be divisible by 10> (no repetition)

I need you help!
Please add a solution so i can understand it

Comment: Do you have any thoughts yourself?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include any work you have done on the problem and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.

Comment: Oops sorry I was just new here. This was second part of take home and can't figure it out. I'll clear next time

Comment: Are you supposed to get help on your take home from places like this?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry sir. I'll be clear next time. This is second part of my homework and just figure it out since we need to self study this one. But I make put effort on my own too.

Answer (score 1):

I'll answer only some of those questions since they look a lot like homework and no personal work is shown.

1) you can choose the first digit in $5$ ways ($6$ ways if a leading $0$ is allowed), the second digit in $5$ ways (the $4$ digits not used for the first digit and $0$) and the last digit in $4$ ways, so we have a total of $5\times5\times4$ ways without leading $0$ and $6\times5\times4$ with leading $0$

2) if a leading $0$ is allowed you can pick every digit in $6$ ways for a total of $6^3$ ways, if a leading $0$ is not allowed then there are $5\times6^2$ ways (can you see why?)

6) A number is divisible by 5 when its last digit is either $5$ or $0$, so we can pick the last digit in $2$ ways, the second digit in $6$ ways and the first in $5$ or $6$ ways depending on whether leading zeros are allowed, for a total of $2\times6^2$ ways with leading zeros and $2\times5\times6$ without

numbers $4$,$5$ and $7$ can be solved exactly like number $6$ by limiting the last digit to few possibilities, number $3$ is slightly different but you can solve it if you think about the constraints that need to be put on the digits

Comment: What does the 6^3 mean sir? Or like 5 x 6^2? Sorry i was quite confused.

So for the number 1. The answer would be 120 if zero is allowed? Am i right?

Comment: Yes, the answer to number $1$ is $120$ if you consider numbers such as $045$ as having 3 digits. $6^3$ means $6\times6\times6$, in general $a^n$ is $a$ multiplied by itsel $b$ times (with $a,b$ integers)